# Regex to match block of text inside square brackets that can be nested

Tags: regex, scala

I'm writing a parser in scala that reads a string composed by repetitions of '+', '-', '<', '>' and '.' characters. The string may also have '[' and ']' characters and inside them there is a repetition of the first group of characters.
I need a Regex that matches everything inside square brackets, the problem is that the brackets can be nested.

I've already tried with this regex: \[.*\] and many others that I've found on SO but none seems to be working.

The regex I'm looking for should work like this:

"[+++.]" matches "+++."

"[++[-]]" should match "++[-]"

edit (added a use case):

"[+++.] [++[-]]" should NOT match "+++.] [++[-]" but 2 matches of "+++." and "++[-]"

Comment: Not sure if this would work in scala [`(?!^)[-.+<>[\]]+(?!$)`](https://regex101.com/r/TJNRsn/1/)

Comment: `the problem is that the brackets can be nested` ... exactly, which is why regex probably is not a suitable solution here.  You should write a simple parser instead.

Comment: Java regex engine used in Scala does not support arbitrary recursion levels. However, you may "hardcode" some recursion levels in a regex. So, you can use regex if you only have 0 to 2 or 3 recursion levels.

Comment: for your examples the regex `\[(.*)\]` (take group 1) should work.

Comment: @Potato thanks for the answer, I'm giving it a try and it gives an exception: "Unclosed character class near index 20" which is at the last ')'

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've already tried with that and I couldn't come up with a solution, the point is that everything inside the square brackets has to be looped an indefinite amount of times and to achieve that I'd just use the parseAll method inside the parser itself. It seemed a smooth solution

Comment: @SergeyLagutin thanks for the answer, I've tried it already but it doesn't work with the use case of: https://regex101.com/r/TJNRsn/2. I that case I need two matches and not one that cuts both of them. My bad if I didnt explain well

Comment: Why not writing a parser as a simple stack machine? This grammar looks simple enough for that

Answer (score 2):

That would be pretty tough with a single regex, but with some post-processing you might get a bit closer.

```
def parse(s :String) :Array[String] = 
  "\\[(.*)\\]".r.unanchored
              .findAllMatchIn(s)
              .toArray
              .flatMap(_.group(1).split(raw"][^\[\]]+\["))
```

usage:

```
parse("+++.]")           //res0: Array[String] = Array()
parse("[+++.]")          //res1: Array[String] = Array("+++.")
parse("[++[-]]")         //res2: Array[String] = Array("++[-]")
parse("[+++.] [++[-]]")  //res3: Array[String] = Array("+++.", "++[-]")
parse("[++[-]--] [+]")   //res4: Array[String] = Array(++[-]--, +)
```

Comment: `parse("[+ + [-] - -] [+]")` looses everything after the first `-` in the first group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's useful however I can't really use it. Your  solution is a function that needs the string ( the parameter s ) while I don't have the string to begin with. What I'm trying to do is to extrapolate it from the text using a regex

Comment: @Jing I don't understand how you expect to parse a string with regex without a string to parse. Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: The regex is used in combination with a parser and I've a way longer string to begin with, using a regex like that would give me the elements like I asked but it would skip everything that is not inside brackets.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I think I may have found the solution, however it is not usable in Scala. What is needed is a recursive regex that matches balanced constructs, in my case:

```
\[(?:[+-\[\]]|(?R))*\]
```

and as far as I know these kind are not supported in scala, so I'll just leave this here if someone needs it for other languages.

However I solved my problem by implementing the parser in another way, I just thought that having a regex like that would have been a simpler and smoother solution.
What I was implementing was a brainfuck language interpreter and here is my parser class:

```
class brainfuck(var pointer: Int, var array: Array[Int]) extends JavaTokenParsers {
    def Program = rep(Statement) ^^ { _ => () }     
    def Statement: Parser[Unit] = 
        "+" ^^ { _ => array(pointer) = array(pointer) + 1 } | 
        "-" ^^ { _ => array(pointer) = array(pointer) - 1 } | 
        "." ^^ { _ => println("elem: " + array(pointer).toChar) } | 
        "," ^^ { _ => array(pointer) = readChar().toInt } |         
        ">" ^^ { _ => pointer = pointer + 1 } |
        "<" ^^ { _ => pointer = pointer - 1 } |
        "[" ~> rep(block|squares) <~ "]" ^^ { items => while(array(pointer)!=0) { parseAll(Program,items.mkString) } }

    def block = 
        """[-+.,<>]""".r ^^ { b => b.toString() }           

    def squares: Parser[String] = "[" ~> rep(block|squares) <~ "]" ^^ { b => var res = "[" + b.mkString + "]"; res }

}
```